# Any better way to perform this task?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

```
def entity_mappings(mapping, entities_list):
    entity_mapped = []
    for (key, value) in mapping.items():
       for i in entities_list:
           if i == key:
                entity_mapped.append(value)
    return entity_mapped
```

I want to match the key from the entities list of ids and append the values of the key in the entity mapped list and return it is there any better way to perform this task?? Mapping is a dict.

Comment: something like: `entity_mapped = [mapping[i] for i in entities_list if i in mapping]` ? Does that produce the expected output?

Comment: or `[mapping[k] for k in set(entities_list) & set(mapping.keys())]`

Comment: Probably best to also provide some sample in- and output. Makes it easier to help.

Comment: mappings = {2:5,6:8,9:87} entities_list = [2,6] entities_mapped =  [5,8] @Cleb

Comment: If you are trying to get the order in which your items were added, consider using the OrderedDict(), then you wouldn't need any mapping matching at all. And if you want filtering, the order in which the items were added would be kept and the list does not have to be in any particular order.

Comment: @Dalen if I want to remove those elements whose mapping is not present from the entities_list what would be the optimal way?

Comment: @HammadKhan : entities_mappings = lambda mapping, exclude: [v for k, v in mapping.iteritems() if k not in exclude]; entities_mappings({1:2,3:4,5:6,7:8,9:10}, set([1,3,7]))
If your exclude list is big, use set() or dict() instead, the search is faster than a list(). This will pass whole mapping exactly once, and each time pass through exclude. Using mapping[k] or mapping.get(k) would be slow because each time whole mapping will be searched for the key.

Comment: @HammadKhan : Accessing a list index, however, is fast. So, you can speed up whole thing by using a system of multiple lists, or even better, deque()s for the mapping instead of the dict,
where one deque() contains values and second that mapps somehow index of the value to the key.
Then you find out indices of values whose keys are going to be excluded and delete them from the deque() of values (which is fast if done properly).
After that, you just return the deque() of values.

Comment: @HammadKhan : To work on excluding keys you can use as much built-in methods/objects as possible (like filter(), set()s, ...) which are fast because they are written in C.
This convoluted method can give you all values in only one very short pass through items you want excluded. It depends on how fast you need it to be whether you would like to enter such an optimization or not.

Comment: @Dalen I want to perform both the tasks together find the mappings and also remove those elements from entities_list whose mapping are not found and return both the list what is the best optimal way to perform this kindly tell me with coding example TIA!

Comment: @HammadKhan : The Q is closed, so there is no space for bigger coding examples. Please post a new Q and try to define more clearly what you wish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this with `list comprehension`,

**Method 1**

```
entity_mapped = [value for (key, value) in mapping.items() if key in entities_list]
```

You can search inside `entities_list` instead of iterating and match.

Complexity: `O(nm)`

**Method 2**

You can search in the dictionary too like this,

```
entity_mapped = [mapping.get(i) for i in entities_list if i in mapping]
```

Complexity : `O(n)`

**Demo**

```
In [16]: mapping = {2:5,6:8,9:87}

In [17]: entities_list = [2,6]

In [18]: print [value for (key, value) in mapping.items() if key in entities_list]
[5, 8]

In [19]: print [mapping.get(i) for i in entities_list if i in mapping]
[5, 8]
```

Comment: You should add that the second version is O(n) while the first is O(nm).

Answer (score 1):

other solution is:

```
[mapping[k] for k in set(entities_list) & set(mapping.keys())]
```

because the dict keys is unique list, example:

```
mapping = {'v':22, 'b': 0, 'd': 44}
entities_list = ['v', 'w', 'd']
```

result is:

```
print([mapping[k] for k in set(entities_list) & set(mapping.keys())])
# [22, 44]
```

Comment: And does this keep the order presented by the list? I think this was the main goal of the exercise.

Comment: @Dalen you right this is does not keep order by, but where you find it in the OP question?

Comment: Nowhere, of course, but when you try something like this, you usually mean to do that, because filtering can be achieved in any number of easy ways. I'll give you +1 for thinking of sets though.

Comment: @Dalen thank you. And i think the sequence is does not metter becuase the method `.items()` has no order.

Comment: Yep, verry correct, so you are probably right. But the code just awakened such association. I might be wrong though. Sets were the first thing that came to my mind when I saw it though. Then map() and then list/generator comprehension.

Comment: if I want to remove those elements whose mapping is not present from the entities_list what would be the optimal way?

Answer (score 1):

I may suggest you to use the [map function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) which can return an iterator that applies a function to every element of a list. For your purpose, the function is `mapping.get` and the list is `entities_list`. it will insert `None` in the output list if the entity is not a key of `mapping` dictionary, as below:

```
def entity_mappings(mapping, entities_list):
    return map(mapping.get, entities_list)

mapping = {2:5, 6:8, 9:87}
entities_list = [2, 6, 5]   # Note that 5 is not a key of mapping

print(list(entity_mappings(mapping, entities_list)))  # [5, 8, None]
```

The same with a generator comprehension gives the following:

```
def entity_mappings(mapping, entities_list):
    return (mapping.get(i) for i in entities_list)

mapping = {2:5, 6:8, 9:87}
entities_list = [2, 6, 5]   # Note that 5 is not a key of mapping

print(list(entity_mappings(mapping, entities_list)))  # [5, 8, None]
```

Using iterators like map or generator objects can save memory because it does not compute and store all the values in memory if you don't need. Instead, it yields one item at a time. Of course the way to do always depend on what you need to do, so you may also prefer using lists directly, no problem with that !

Comment: if I want to remove those elements whose mapping is not present from the entities_list what would be the optimal way?